# Prove a set is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Let $H = \{x \in G: x = y^2 \text { for some } y \in G\}$. Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

---

Let $x, y \in H.$ Then, $xy = y^2z^2 = yyzz.$ Since $H$ is abelian $yyzz = yzyz = (yz)^2.$ So, $xy \in H.$

Since $e = e^2, e \in H.$

$x^{-1} = (y^2)^{-1} = (y^{-1})^2.$

So, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Please, check if it works.

Comment: Yes, this is done correctly.

Comment: Please don't use same notation for two different (!) things. (here $x=y^2$ and again $y=z^2$) Otherwise it's fine.

Comment: Small error, should have said $xy=s^2t^2$, the $y$ incorrectly got double-used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea but you're reusing variables.

It should have been something like:

1. Let $x, y \in H$, then $x = s^2$, $y = t^2$ for some $s, t \in G$. Then $xy = s^2t^2 = (st)(st) = (st)^2$ (by commutativity of $G$) which means $xy \in H$.
2. $e \in H$ since $e = e^2$.
3. Let $x \in H$, then $x = s^2$ for some $s \in G$. $x^{-1} = (s^2)^{-1} = s^{-2} = (s^{-1})^2$ and hence $x^{-1} \in H$.

So now you can conclude, by definition, that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Also, you should probably have a lemma or two showing that you can even do the exponent arithmetic as we did above.